# Upload Image with AJAX using blade

Tags: ajax, image, laravel, upload, laravel-blade

I trying to upload image using ajax in Laravel 5. I am using following code but nothing happends:

image.blade.php

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'ImageController@store','files'=>true,'id'=>'upload_form'))}}
   Title: {{Form::text('title')}}
   Image: {{Form::file('image')}}
   {{Form::submit('submit',['id' => 'btnAddProduct'])}}
   {{Form::close()}}

    @include('flash::message')
```

ImageController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $destinationpath = public_path() . '/img/';

    $image=$request->input('image');
    $filename=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('image')->move( $destinationpath,$filename );

    return Response::json(['success' => true, 'file' => asset($destinationpath.$filename)]);
}
```

Ajax code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitButtonId').on('click', function() {
    $.ajsubmitButtonIdax({
  url:'/imgC/store',
  data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
  dataType:'json',
  async:false,
  type:'post',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success:function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
 });
});
});     
</script>
```

Route.php:

```
Route::resource('imgC', 'ImageController');
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's not working?

Comment: Its just directing me to the page with this :{"success":true,"file":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/C:\\wamp\\www\\laravel\\work\\public\/img\/4d26e7d0eaf822d4790bf9b793ac58dc.jpg"} nothing is saved in db

Comment: But there is no code in the `store` method that saves anything in the database. You're just moving the uploaded file to the `public/img`.

Comment: what code should I put in? in order to get it uploaded using ajax

Comment: The easiest way would be to have an [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models) for your `images` table and so you can easily store the title and file path in the database.

Comment: This is done with ajax?

Comment: I have a model for Image also. but when i save image to db using that. its not ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105802/discussion-between-rida-mukhtar-and-bogdan).